# Cometário estilo Instagram ( em React Native)

Tags: css, react-native

tenho uma dúvida que imagino que seja simples, porém não estou conseguindo, gostaria de saber como posso fazer isso no React Native.

Segue a imagem como exemplo:

[image: comentário no Instagram]

São dois textos, um em negrito (nome do usuário) e outro (comentário) com estilo padrão porém quebrando a linha e aparecendo abaixo do usuário mesmo na linha seguinte.

Consigo fazer isso utilizando apenas uma View e dois Text? Ou precisa de algo a mais?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando dois `<Text>`. O primeiro `<Text>` seria um "container" geral dos textos. E dentro deste componente pode-se inserir outro `<Text>`, só que estilizado da maneira como preferir.

Exemplos (Apesar de os componentes estarem como nomes diferente, todos são o componente `<Text>`):

```xml
<TextContainer>
   <BoldText>nomeDoUsuário</BoldText> Comentário do usuário.
</TextContainer>

// O compomente BoldText, obviamente, deve ter a 
// estilização aplicada para refletir seu resultado.
```

Desta maneira será possível aplicar o estilo desejado e o comportamento desejado. Fazendo com que o texto do comentário ocupe toda o espaço disponível.

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu desejava, consigo aplicar estilos em cada texto e eles ocupam a mesma linha. Muito obrigado!